# How to use a terminal in qt-creator?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, qt-creator

How can I setup qt-creator in such manner that when I use 'run', a terminal will get used? I need that for input from std::cin. I use version 4.14 on Lubuntu 20.4 LTS.

Comment: Have you created a console application?

Comment: Yes, I choosed this selection.

Answer (score 0):

In the left pane, Click `projects -> Run` and check `Run in terminal`.

Comment: Now I get this error message when I try to run the Program:

Comment: 12:06:10: The process failed to start. Either the invoked program "/home/nicos/develop/cpp/other/build-qt_test_2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/qt_test_2" is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.
12:06:10: Cannot change to working directory "/home/nicos/develop/cpp/other/build-qt_test_2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug": No such file or directory
12:06:10: /home/nicos/develop/cpp/other/build-qt_test_2-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/qt_test_2 exited with code -1

Comment: @NicoSchumann, seems like a misConfig, double check project path